# Dispose of ReactiveCommand after execution

Tags: c#, wpf, system.reactive, reactiveui

I'm binding a `LoadedCommand` using `System.Windows.Interactivity` like so:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LoadedCommand}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

And in my view-model I am loading data when the view is loaded:

```
LoadedCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(LoadData);
```

My problem is that the Loaded event is actually triggered multiple times by the parent view. I would like to stop the `LoadedCommand` after its first execution without doing something like:

```
async Task LoadData()
{
    if (didLoad) return;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky one because the Load handler is called multiple times. It's annoying. So we have some helper code to get around this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reactive.Disposables;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Windows;

namespace Utils
{
    public static class FrameworkElementExtensions
    {
        public static void LoadUnloadHandler
            ( this FrameworkElement control
            , Func<IDisposable> action)
        {
            var state = false;
            var cleanup = new SerialDisposable();
            Observable.Merge
                (Observable.Return(control.IsLoaded)
                    , control.Events().Loaded.Select(x => true)
                    , control.Events().Unloaded.Select(x => false)
                )
                .Subscribe(isLoadEvent =>
                {
                    if (!state)
                    {
                        // unloaded state
                        if (isLoadEvent)
                        {
                            state = true;
                            cleanup.Disposable = 
                                new CompositeDisposable(action());
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // loaded state
                        if (!isLoadEvent)
                        {
                            state = false;
                            cleanup.Disposable = Disposable.Empty;
                        }
                    }

                });
        }


    }
}
```

The code handles the **Load** and **Unload** event and filters out the multiple call problem. The idea is that you provide a callback that does something on **Load** and returns an **IDisposable** that will be disposed on **Unload**.

For example if you need to register to an outside resource such as a network connection but only when the control is visible you could do in the code behind constructor.

```
this.LoadUnloadHandler(()=>{
    MyViewModel.Connect();
    return Disposable.Create(()=>MyViewModel.Disconnect());
});
```

Classes / Libraries used

- [Disposable.Create](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.disposables.disposable.create(v=vs.103).aspx)
- [SerialDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.disposables.serialdisposable(v=vs.103).aspx)
- [Observable.Merge](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.linq.observable.merge(v=vs.103).aspx)
- [CompositeDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.disposables.compositedisposable(v=vs.103).aspx)
- [ReactiveUI.Events](https://www.nuget.org/packages/reactiveui-events/)

Comment: I was trying to avoid writing code in the code-behind. If I were to write in there could I do `Observable.FromEventPattern(this, LoadedEvent.Name).Take(1).Subscribe(async _ => await ViewModel.LoadData());`? `Take(1)` should dispose of my `Observable`, correct?

Comment: That will work if you only want it to happen once when loaded and probably is OK for your exact need. My code will run correctly on each real load, skipping double calls and dispose any resource on unload. I use it all the time especially if registering to global resources from code behind that I need to clean up.   FromEventPattern is however rather Fugly. I would recommend using ReactiveUI.Events as I have done but that's more of a taste issue and not critical.  Also don't avoid the code behind. Trying to do some stuff in XAML is just a pain in the arse.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 1):

Set command to null in LoadData method. So you don't need to maintain a separate flag for this.

```
async Task LoadData()
{
    // your logic goes here
    LoadedCommand = null;
}
```

Comment: I tried that but the `LoadData` method is still called.